# Map markets with entered address using Meteor

Tags: google-maps, meteor, leaflet

I'm trying to have a map, leaflet or google maps that creates markers based on a loop containing addresses in Meteor. I've been looking through some packages but confused how to use the loop within the parameters. Below is the code, any help would be much appreciated!

collection:

```
Homes = new Mongo.Collection('daycares');

Homes.attachSchema(new SimpleSchema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    label: "Daycare Name",
    max: 100
  },
  address: {
    type: String,
    label: "Address",
    max: 100
  },
  yib: {
    type: Number,
    label: "Years in Business"
  },
  contactname: {
  type: String,
  label: "Contact Name",
  max: 100
  },
  phone: {
    type: Number,
    label: "Phone Number"
  },
  licensed: {
    type: Boolean,
    label: "Licensed?"
  },
  description: {
    type: String,
    label: "Description"
  },
    userId: {
    type: String,
    optional: true,
    autoValue: function () {
      return this.userId;
    }
  }
}));


if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Homes.allow({
    insert: function (userId, doc) {
      return true;
    },

    update: function (userId, doc, fieldNames, modifier) {
      return true;
    },

    remove: function (userId, doc) {
      return true;
    }
  });

  // Homes.deny({
  //   insert: function (userId, doc) {
  //     return true;
  //   },

  //   update: function (userId, doc, fieldNames, modifier) {
  //     return true;
  //   },

  //   remove: function (userId, doc) {
  //     return true;
  //   }
  // });
}
```

html:

```
<template name="ListHomes">
  <h1>Home List</h1>
  <table class="table table-hover">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Address</th>
        <th>Years in Business</th>
        <th>Contact Name</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Phone Number</th>
        <th>Licensed</th>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th>Userid</th>
        <th>Edit</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      {{#each homes}}
        <tr>
          <td>{{name}}</td>
          <td>{{address}}</td>
          <td>{{yib}}</td>
          <td>{{contactname}}</td>
          <td>{{userEmail userId}}</td>
          <td>{{phone}}</td>
          <td>{{licensed}}</td>
          <td>{{description}}</td>
          <td>{{userId}}</td>
          <td>{{#linkTo route='editDaycare'}}<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span>{{/linkTo}}</td>
        </tr>
      {{/each}}
    </tbody>
  </table></template>
```

js:

```
/*****************************************************************************/
    /* ListHomes: Event Handlers */
    /*****************************************************************************/
    Template.ListHomes.events({
    });

    /*****************************************************************************/
    /* ListHomes: Helpers */
    /*****************************************************************************/
    Template.ListHomes.helpers({
        homes: function() {
            return Homes.find();
        }

    });

    UI.registerHelper('userEmail', function(context, options) {
      if(context)
        return Meteor.users.findOne(context).emails[0].address;
    });

    /*****************************************************************************/
    /* ListHomes: Lifecycle Hooks */
    /*****************************************************************************/
    Template.ListHomes.created = function () {
    };

    Template.ListHomes.rendered = function () {
    };

    Template.ListHomes.destroyed = function () {
    };
```

Comment: What have you tried with the code that Leaflet, GMaps, etc gives you for creating markers?

Comment: As a suggestion, forget about Collections and Helpers for now. Just pick Leaflet or Gmaps or whatever and work on displaying a map and adding one marker onto the map with hardcoded info. Then do the same but put three markers on the map with hardcoded info. After that you should be able to see how to tie it into Collections.